# Calendar not updating on button click when passing new array

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, date-fns

I'm using Vue 3, TailwindCSS, and `date-fns` to create a calendar. However, when I pass a new array with the dates the calendar doesn't change.

When the button is clicked the `{{currentMonth}}` changes in the title. However the days do not change. I've added `nextM` to the `nextMonth` function to make sure a new array is created and then I pass it to the days object containing all the previous dates.

```js
// Using `<script setup>`

import { parseJSON, startOfToday, format, eachDayOfInterval, startOfWeek, endOfWeek, startOfMonth, endOfMonth, isSameMonth, isToday, isSameDay, parse, add, sub} from 'date-fns'
import { ref } from 'vue'

let todaysDate = startOfToday()
let currentDay = todaysDate

let formatedDate = format(currentDay, 'MMM, yyyy')
let currentMonth = ref(formatedDate)

let getNewDays = parse(currentMonth.value, 'MMM, yyyy', new Date())
console.log('getNewDays ', getNewDays)
let firstDayCurrentMonth = parse(currentMonth.value, 'MMM, yyyy', new Date())

const check = parse(currentMonth.value, 'MMM, yyyy', new Date())
console.log('Check', check)

let days = eachDayOfInterval({
    start: startOfWeek(startOfMonth(getNewDays), {weekStartsOn: 1}),
    end: endOfWeek(endOfMonth(getNewDays), {weekStartsOn: 1})
})

days = days.map((dates) => {
    return {
        date: format(dates, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
        isCurrentMonth: isSameMonth(getNewDays, dates),
        isToday: isToday(dates),
        isSelected: isSameDay(dates, currentDay),
        events: []
    }
})

function nextMonth()
{
    let firstDayCurrentMonth = parse(currentMonth.value, 'MMM, yyyy', new Date())
    let firstDayNextMonth = add(firstDayCurrentMonth, { months: 1})

    currentMonth.value = format(firstDayNextMonth, 'MMM, yyyy')

    const result = parse(currentMonth.value, 'MMM, yyyy', new Date())

    let nextM = eachDayOfInterval({
    start: startOfWeek(startOfMonth(firstDayNextMonth), {weekStartsOn: 1}),
    end: endOfWeek(endOfMonth(firstDayNextMonth), {weekStartsOn: 1})
    })

    nextM = nextM.map((dates) => {
        return {
        date: format(dates, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
        isCurrentMonth: isSameMonth(getNewDays, dates),
        isToday: isToday(dates),
        isSelected: isSameDay(dates, currentDay),
        events: []
    } 
    })

    days = nextM

    console.log(days)
    getNewDays = result
    console.log(getNewDays)
}
```

```html
          <div class="hidden w-full lg:grid lg:grid-cols-7 lg:grid-rows-6 lg:gap-px">
            <div v-for="day in days" :key="day.date"  @click="selectDate(day)" :class="[day.isCurrentMonth ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-gray-50 text-gray-500', 'relative py-2 px-3']">
              <time :datetime="day.date" :class="day.isToday ? 'flex h-6 w-6 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-indigo-600 font-semibold text-white' : undefined">{{ day.date.split('-').pop().replace(/^0/, '') }}</time>
              <ol v-if="day.events.length > 0" class="mt-2">
                <li v-for="event in day.events.slice(0, 2)" :key="event.id">
                  <a :href="event.href" class="group flex">
                    <p class="flex-auto truncate font-medium text-gray-900 group-hover:text-indigo-600">
                      {{ event.name }}
                    </p>
                    <time :datetime="event.datetime" class="ml-3 hidden flex-none text-gray-500 group-hover:text-indigo-600 xl:block">{{ event.time }}</time>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li v-if="day.events.length > 2" class="text-gray-500">+ {{ day.events.length - 2 }} more</li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I've attempted to clean up the code:

```js
import { parseJSON, startOfToday, format, eachDayOfInterval, startOfWeek, endOfWeek, startOfMonth, endOfMonth, isSameMonth, isToday, isSameDay, parse, add, sub} from 'date-fns'
import { ref } from 'vue'

let today = startOfToday()
let formatedDate = format(today, 'MMM, yyyy')
let currentMonth = ref(formatedDate)

let getNewDays = parse(currentMonth.value, 'MMM, yyyy', new Date())

let days = eachDayOfInterval({
    start: startOfWeek(startOfMonth(parse(currentMonth.value, 'MMM, yyyy', new Date())), {weekStartsOn: 1}),
    end: endOfWeek(endOfMonth(parse(currentMonth.value, 'MMM, yyyy', new Date())), {weekStartsOn: 1})
})

days = days.map((dates) => {
    return {
        date: format(dates, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
        isCurrentMonth: isSameMonth(getNewDays, dates),
        isToday: isToday(dates),
        isSelected: isSameDay(dates, today),
        events: []
    }
})

function nextMonth()
{
    let firstDayCurrentMonth = parse(currentMonth.value, 'MMM, yyyy', new Date())
    console.log(firstDayCurrentMonth)
    let firstDayNextMonth = add(firstDayCurrentMonth, {months: 1})
    currentMonth.value = format(firstDayNextMonth, 'MMM, yyyy')
    console.log(firstDayNextMonth)
    console.log(currentMonth.value)
    console.log(days)
    console.log(parse(currentMonth.value, 'MMM, yyyy', new Date()))
}

function selectDate(day)
{
    console.log(day)
}

const selectedDay = days.find((day) => day.isSelected)
```

Comment: To help us help you, could you reproduce this in a Vue Codepen?

Comment: "When the button is clicked the {{currentMonth}} changes in the title." When what button is clicked? `nextMonth` is never used in the code you've given. What title?; `currentMonth` seems to be only used in calculations. Is this _all_ the relevant code?

Comment: ```          <time datetime="2022-01">{{currentMonth}}</time>
``` Sorry I havve this as the title of the calendar

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-pinia-all-in-one-nchvzw?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FPiniaLogo.vue,package.json

Answer (score 0):

Initially I wrote the code for composition API, however it seems that you need to wrap the code in a ref to make it reactive. I've now re-written the code in the options API which automatically wraps all data values in a ref making everything reactive.